# Jqgrid on Edit operation sends "add" as oper="add" why?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a weird one. After changing the data store from session to oracle, when i hit Edit on the 'inlineNav' it always goes to the server with the "add" operation. Any ideas why this could happened?

```
$("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid({
            url: 'orthofixServices.asmx/GetProductList',
            colNames: ['id', 'Product Description', 'Commission Rate'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'id' },
            { name: 'description', index: 'desc', width: 170, editable: true },
            { name: 'commissionrate', index: 'com', width: 80, editable: true, unformat: percentUnFormatter, formatter: percentFormatter, editrules: { number: true} }
            ],
            serializeRowData: function(data) {

                var params = new Object();
                params.id = 0;
                params.prdid = parseInt($("#prdid").val());
                params.description = data.description;
                params.commissionrate = data.commissionrate;
                return JSON.stringify({ 'passformvalue': params, 'oper': data.oper, 'id': data.id });
            },
            mtype: "POST",
            rowNum: 4,
            height: 93,
            width: 400,
            pager: '#assessmentpager',
            editurl: "orthofixServices.asmx/ModifyProductList"
        });
        $("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid('navGrid', '#assessmentpager', { add: false, edit: false, del: true, refresh: false, search: false }, {}, {}, { serializeDelData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify({ 'passformvalue': null, 'oper': postData.oper, 'id': postData.id });
        }
        });
        $("#assessmentproduct").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#assessmentpager', { addParams: { position: "last", addRowParams: {
            "aftersavefunc": function() { var grid = $("#assessmentproduct"); reloadgrid(grid); }
        }
        }, editParams: { "aftersavefunc": function() { var grid = $("#assessmentproduct"); reloadgrid(grid); } }
        });
```

Comment: Per default post `inlineNav` the data as `myCoumnName=maData&oper=add&id=new_row`. So the value of the operations will *not* quoted. If you have another results you should include the JavaScript code which shows how you define jqGrid.

Comment: when debuging javascript on serializeRowData: function(data) {... data.oper="add". Even when i am in editing mode. So it is not the serialization, it is the state in which the grid says it is at that point!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `JSON.stringify` inside of `serializeRowData` to serialize the posted data to JSON. It's the reason of the encoding which you describe.

**UPDATED**: OK! Now I see at the end what's the problem. The reason of the misunderstanding was because you used `oper="add"` in the title instead of `oper=add`. I understood you that *this* is your problem (sending of quoted `oper="add"` instead of `oper=add`). OK. The problem with sending of `oper=add` in case of `edit` operation is known jqGrid bug which is already fixed in the code on the github (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/3bbb9505aa4aa281144a1d320b7e55572eaf2d6b)). You can make the same changes in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and use the fixed code till the new version of jqGrid will released.

Comment: No, it is not the serialization..when I debug serializeRowData: function(data) {...at this point data.oper="add", which is incorrect. because i got here by pressing edit on the grid. So eventhough i started an edit operation when it serialize it is giving me data.oper="add" which should not be the actual state of the grid

Comment: @ManuelValle: You should replace code `return JSON.stringify({'passformvalue': params, 'oper': data.oper, 'id': data.id });` to two lines `var result = JSON.stringify({'passformvalue': params, 'oper': data.oper, 'id': data.id });` and `return result;`. You will see how the `result` looks like.

Comment: Ok, I added the second line to get results this is what it gets: {"passformvalue":{"id":0,"prdid":2,"description":"DESC 3/8/2012 2:56:49 PM","commissionrate":"5"},"oper":"add","id":"63"}, But again I am issuing an edit operation and as you see "oper":"add".

Comment: @ManuelValle: Is `"oper":"add"` not what you means in your question? By the way during the debugging you know what post jqGrid to the server. Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can see the HTTP traffic and verify one more time that exactly the data will be send to the server. So if you get on the server additional quotes in the name of the `oper` it should be some problem in the server code and not in an jqGrid problem.

Comment: I use firebug. the add and delete operations are fine. When I issue an edit operation then it shows "oper":"add" where it should say "oper":"edit". It shows everywhere, on serializing, on firegub request and on the server parameter of method signature....So when i get to the server the code tries to add a new item to the table where it should be editing an existing row...

Comment: @ManuelValle: OK! Now I see at the end what's the problem. The reason of the misunderstanding was becase you used `oper="add"` in the title of the question instead of `oper=add`. I understood you that *this* is your problem. OK. The problem with sending of `oper=add` in case of `edit` operation is known jqGrid bug which is already fixed in the code on the github (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/3bbb9505aa4aa281144a1d320b7e55572eaf2d6b)). You can make the same changes in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and use the fixed code till the new version of jqGrid will released.